# HTML Syntax Highlighting within Freemarker .FTL Spring STS

Tags: html, eclipse, syntax-highlighting, freemarker

After a clean install of Spring Tool Suite and the necessary plugins my current project requires (of which Freemarker is one) I find that HTML seems to be ignored within all of my .FTLs and is just displayed as black text (see image of settings). Prior to this, any HTML tags, comments and strings were picked up and highlighted in the default colours given.
To clarify, now it's only the Freemarker specific syntax that is now detected.(Directives - Blue and Freemarker variables - Pink)

If anyone knows how to fix this issue I would be greatly appreciative!

[Freemarker Preferences Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KxTTM.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBIDE-22631. If you are using file `.html.ftl` or `.xml.ftl` (or `ftlh` or `ftlx` when JBIDE-22636 will be merged) file extension, it starts doing some highlighting, though it doesn't colorize the attributes differently anymore.

Comment: Yeah that's my issue. The .html.ftl fix is a decent one, though not convenient when working with so many files. Thanks for the link and the temp solution. Very helpful, upvote will arrive just as soon as my rep allows it.

Comment: Actually doing it for `.ftl` isn't right, because `.ftl` is often non-HTML. But surely that should be still an option under the plug-in preferences. Also new projects should opt for `ftlh` and `ftlx`, because with `recognize_standard_file_extensions setting` set to `true` or with `incompatible_improvements` set to at least `2.3.24` those will turn on auto-escaping, and also because many tools has problem with double extensions (like `.html.ftl`).